# How can I add query parameter(s) to the URL in Navigator.share() based on where its shared?

Tags: javascript, html, navigator, utm-tracking

I'm using `window.navigator.share({url})` . This makes it share the same `url` to all apps in the device.

Is it possible to add specific query parameter(I want to add `utm` parameters) for each app?

For example, if the user selected WhatsApp to share, then I can add the parameter `?utm_source=Whatsapp` to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) interface.

```
let url = new URL('https://example.com/some/path?foo=1&bar=2');
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search.slice(1));

params.set('utm', 'whatsapp')

// params.toString() : "foo=1&bar=2&utm=whatsapp"
url.search = params.toString()

console.log(url.href)
// "https://example.com/some/path?foo=1&bar=2&utm=whatsapp"
```

Comment: Adding the parameter to the URL isn't the problem here. What I want is a way to identify whether I should add the parameter value `whatsapp` or whether I want to add the parameter value `telegram` for the key `utm` . So, essentially, I want to know which app a user selects in the drawer that opens on `window.navigator.share({url})`

Comment: The `navigator.share()` method returns an empty promise if it's successful or an exception on failure.